# How to assign value to a variable using string in Java (not evaluation)

Tags: java, math, eval

Let's say I have,

1. A string `String foo = "a+b"`
2. Variable `a` and `b`, `Integer a = 2` `Integer b = 3`

I want to somehow assign new Integer, `c` which should be calculated from `a` and `b` using the String `foo`.

The eval didn't work as it can only compute things with absolute values not values of variables.

Comment: You can write parser or see this question. [Stackowerflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2605032/is-there-an-eval-function-in-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the JEP Java expression parser libary (or another expression parser).

For example:

```
String foo = "a+b";
Jep jep = new Jep();
try {
    jep.addVariable("a", a);
    jep.addVariable("b", b);
    jep.parse(foo);
    Object result = jep.evaluate();     
    System.out.println("foo = " + result);
} catch (JepException e) {
    System.out.println("An error occurred: " + e.getMessage());
}
```

**EDIT:**

It turns out that JEP (here: http://www.singularsys.com/jep/) is licensed software so you will have to pay, but there is another option.

There are many other similar libraries including *JEPLite* (http://jeplite.sourceforge.net/index.html) which seems (as far as I can tell) to be a free version and should be compatible.